# How to access Control (div) in MasterPage from separate Class file

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, webforms, master-pages

I have MP.Master, default.aspx, *MyClass.cs*

There's a **div** in MP.Master with attribute *"runat=server"*.

In default.aspx.cs, i call **MyMethod()** that is in *MyClass.cs* file.

I am not being able to access the **div**, to use in **MyMethod()**. How can i access it from *MyClass.cs*?

Comment: From Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

Comment: I can't add the MasterType directive in the content page because MyMethod() is in a separate MyClass.cs file.

Comment: What if you added the MasterType directive in the content page, accessed the div control, and passed it to MyMethod as a parameter. Would that be a viable option for you?

Comment: @user Have you had a chance to try the solution? If so, is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I tested my comment and confirmed that it works. Here's a quick sample. It changes the text of your div's innerHTML to "test".

Div in you master page (MP.Master):

```
<div runat="server" id="myDiv"></div>
```

Property in the code behind of your master page (MP.Master.cs):

```
public HtmlGenericControl TheDiv {
    get { return myDiv; }
}
```

MasterType directive at the top of your aspx page:

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/MP.Master" %>
```

Code behind of that page (you could put this in a button click, page load, etc.):

```
TestClass test = new TestClass();
test.MyMethod(Master.TheDiv);
```

TestClass (TestClass is like your MyClass):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void MyMethod(HtmlGenericControl div)
    {
        div.InnerHtml = "Test";
    }
}
```